# Raster calculator gives an output with mostly NoData values

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, nodata

I am using QGIS 3.20 and have an area with the whole extent covered by 4 different layers, but when I perform a raster calculation to sum up the cell values, I only get scattered results in a mostly blank extent. I'm trying with sum and multiply, and the results are similar (except for the values, of course).

`"LandUse_rast1@1" + "natvegrast1@1" + "roads_raster1@1" + "water_raster1@1"`

Input
[image: Input layers]
Output
[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WHY THIS HAPPENS:**

From your screenshots it looks as if some of your layers have cells without data (NA-values). Otherwise it would not be possible to display the layers above each other (unless you have set specific values to be transparent).

If you **perform calculations on cells with NA-values** e.g. `NA + x` or `NA * x` (x being a decimal or integer value) **the raster calculator will yield results that are also NA for the given cell**.

This is, why you have output for just a few cells - these are cells, where all 4 overlapping layers hold a *non*-NA value.

**WHAT TO DO ABOUT IT:**

Depending on the goal of your calculation (not clearly stated). I would recommend you:

- use the `Fill NoData Cells` tool. This will replace NA with a given value.
- If you performe **additions** fill with 0
- If you performe **multiplications** fill with 1